# NSNotification not calling the selector

Tags: iphone, nsnotifications

I am creating a `NSNotification` in **appDelegate**.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkRegister:) name:@"checkRegister" object:nil];

    return YES;
}

-(void)checkRegister:(NSNotification *) notification{

//Some code

}
```

And I am posting notification in some other class:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);
    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",theXML);
    [theXML release];

    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: webData];
    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];
    [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities: YES];
    [xmlParser parse];
    [xmlParser release];

    [connection release];
    [webData release];

    if(strUserName != NULL)
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"checkRegister" object:nil];


}
```

The problem is that checkRegister is never called.

Comment: Where is `strUserName` set? How do you know the notification is getting posted? Have you put a breakpoint on that line and verified that it's getting called?

Comment: It is set in parsing. It is not the issue. I am not able to call the method checkRegister.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the purpose of your `@"checkRegister"` notification, you have `if(strUserName != NULL)` check in your if before you post the notification, but I don't see where do you setup that `strUserName` so definitely, try `NSLog(@"%@", strUserName)`. I'm pretty sure it's null. if that `strUserName` is from the XML data your parse, you should post the notification after XML parsing code, which will be in your `NSXMLParser` delegate methods you implement. Which will be [one of these you use.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSXMLParserDelegate)

`[xmlParser parse]` doesn't block, so your

```
if(strUserName != NULL)
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"checkRegister" object:nil];
```

will be called, before `xmlParser` finished parsing, so, your strUserName is not set yet, and that's the reason it is nil and your `postNoticationName:` will not be called

EDIT:

put your

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkRegister:) name:@"checkRegister" object:nil];
```

on the very top of your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` , it is very likely you post the notification in your main view before you registered for notification, for example

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkRegister:) name:@"checkRegister" object:nil];
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.mainViewController = [[[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    } else {
        self.mainViewController = [[[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = self.mainViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

will work, while

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.mainViewController = [[[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    } else {
        self.mainViewController = [[[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = self.mainViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkRegister:) name:@"checkRegister" object:nil];
    return YES;
}
```

will not work if your data loading is done in `MainControllerView` `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: X Slash : You are not understanding my point. I my add delegate call, when I am creating notification and adding checkRegister in selector which is in same class. But the selector is never called. What you are saying is also correct but is the later part. The first thing is, the selecotr should be called.

Comment: selector will not be called because your strUserName == nil. It's nil because you set it up in your NSXML delegate, which at the time of your postNotificationName: is not done yet. If you don't believe me, just remove if (strUserName != NULL) from your code.

Comment: I commented it. Still selector not being called.

Comment: see my edited answer, below edit, I think that might be your problem, also still leave if (strUserName != NULL) commented, I think that might still cause some problems.