# How can I guarantee registering for a notification happens in a view controller before didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiapplicationdelegate

Specifically, I want to register for a notification -before posted by the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`- in my main view controller so I can perform a task from the 'splash' (forgive me Ob-C nerds, forgot what its really called) screen without doing the ominous

```
[[[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] topViewController] functionIwantToCallOnceAtTheStart];
```

Side note: I love the idea of having a 'global start whistle,' why is this not a default?

Logging `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and the root view controller's delegate methods results in

```
2013-07-25 02:02:46.532 Tests[918:c07] awakeFromNib
2013-07-25 02:02:46.535 Tests[918:c07] didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
2013-07-25 02:02:46.538 Tests[918:c07] viewDidLoad
2013-07-25 02:02:46.539 Tests[918:c07] viewWillAppear
2013-07-25 02:02:46.540 Tests[918:c07] viewWillLayoutSubviews
2013-07-25 02:02:46.543 Tests[918:c07] viewDidLayoutSubviews
2013-07-25 02:02:46.544 Tests[918:c07] viewWillLayoutSubviews
2013-07-25 02:02:46.545 Tests[918:c07] viewDidLayoutSubviews
2013-07-25 02:02:46.549 Tests[918:c07] viewDidAppear
```

but is it guaranteed that `awakeFromNib` will always come before didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, and on all iOS devices/versions?

[This question has a helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075227/nsnotification-not-calling-the-selector) but my project is using storyboards, and I am unsure of the implications of setting the rootViewController manually with a storyboard.

**Edit**:

I originally asked this question because I wanted to have the launch image animate away. I realize there are better methods to do this, but I still want to use the "Application Started" notification to launch a network request to populate my main view controller (a UITableViewController) as soon as the app is started.

Comment: Probably should've asked this when the whole western hemisphere wasn't sleeping...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awakeFromNib` is guaranteed to be called on the initial view controller of your storyboard before applicationDidFinishLaunching is called. Loading from the nib is part of the launch.

However, its not really clear from the question what you're trying to do. While the launch image is displayed, your view controller isn't really there, so what are you asking it to do? None of the UI objects will be present until it has loaded, so whatever task you're trying to do may not come under the responsibility of a view controller.

Comment: I wanted to have the effect of tiling away the launch image. But I suppose this could be achieved by having the root view controller be a UIImageView that tiles away on `viewDidAppear:`. But I have another app that I want to implement the 'global start whistle' to begin a network request that will load the main view, which is a table view of nearby locations.

Comment: Yes, for that effect you typically need an image view which holds the same image as your launch image, its a bit of a pain. Your network requests should be kicked off from whenever the VC that needs them needs them, don't put too much responsibility on the app delegate.

Comment: I agree, which is why I want to use notifications- so the view controller can call the networking operation. But I need this to only run after the app is first started. Sure, I could use awakeFromNib (which isn't [necessarily](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092366/awakefromnib-method-called-multiple-times) called once), or store some `isFirstLoad` item in NSUserDefaults, but these options are tricky, long-winded, and hacky.

Comment: I don't think your network-on-first-run thing is an appropriate use case. Sooner or later you're going to want to refresh the data in there. Why not call it on viewDidLoad? The view won't get loaded again unless the VC is deallocated, assuming iOS6+.

Comment: I have a pull-to-refresh that can be utilized at will, I just wanted to have the application populate with fresh results on startup. And I am currently using `dispatch_once` so I can achieve the effect I want, but I still think a *didStart* notification would make a whole lot of sense design wise.

Answer (score 1):

If you really really want to run some code, you can open up the main class. It's in your project under supporting files.

Also, this guide explains quite a bit on the appication startup sequence:

http://oleb.net/blog/2012/02/app-launch-sequence-ios-revisited/

Comment: Good link. But I am not comfortable putting application code in main(). I feel like it's bad enough to write code in the appDelegate. Besides, my purpose for using notifications is so I can avoid the ugly `[[[[..]..]..]..]` code that gives me access to the rootViewController, while still running the code only after the initial startup sequence. The code to get the rootViewController from main() to handle the callback would be disheartening.

Answer (score 1):

The point of the launch image is to make your app appear to launch faster than it really does by putting a static image on screen as soon as possible. As long as your launch image looks exactly like whatever view your initial view controller shows, nobody will know the difference. If you want that initial image to animate away somehow, no problem:

- Create an initial view controller that displays your image and does a [custom transition](http://www.vigorouscoding.com/2011/05/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/) to your next view controller.
- If the image you're displaying covers the screen exactly, you can also use that image as the launch image. Otherwise, run the app and do a screen capture when the first view controller's view appears; make that screen shot your launch image.
- Put some code in your `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method to start the transition from the initial view controller to the next one.

That should do it. Remember that the launch image is a sort of implementation detail -- the user isn't supposed to be aware of it as a separate thing, so it's natural to do what you're trying to do as a view controller transition instead of fooling around with the launch image itself.

Comment: This is great information, but my main concern (see the **edit** or my comments on @jrturton's answer) is launching a network request to update my UITableViewController, but only after launch.

Comment: @user Sorry -- missed that aspect of the question. I'd just use `dispatch_once()` from your launch method to fire off the network request. It sounds like you don't want to launch the network request if your launch method is called more than once, and `dispatch_once()` will guarantee that the block you give it runs only once for the lifetime of the app.

Comment: Yep, now I remember reading something about that. But even though it's only a few milliseconds to check the `dispatch_once_t` token, I prefer to avoid repeatedly checking state if I can help it. After working on a project that was all switches and spaghetti, I've been conditioned to run from state machines.

Comment: @Caleb- `dispatch_once` is the most tried and true option I've come across so far though. Will use that in the interim.